# Can't calculate Latitude. using Formula

Tags: c#, gps, physics

I need to calculate Longitude and Latitude based on an old Longitude and Latitude, with distance and direction from that point.

From this link: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I got these Formulae:

```
newLatitude = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(oldLatitude) * Math.Cos(distanceTravelled / earthRadius) + Math.Cos(oldLatitude) * Math.Sin(distanceTravelled / earthRadius) * Math.Cos(currentDirection));

newLongitude = oldLongitude + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(currentDirection) * Math.Sin(distanceTravelled / earthRadius) * Math.Cos(oldLatitude), Math.Cos(distanceTravelled / earthRadius) - Math.Sin(oldLatitude) * Math.Sin(oldLatitude));
```

I have Acceleration e.g. 0.1 m/sec2

time travelled: Calculated from current time - start time.

Then I calculate the Distance travelled:

```
 distanceTravelled = distanceTravelled/1000;
```

I also have movement of direction in degrees: e.g. 90 degree. (East)

But I am getting Error in new Latitude see-image:

[image]

Do I have to enter direction in Radian?

Distance in KM instead of meter?

Please help me get the right Latitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at the solution.
I was using degree and decimal of latitude and longitude in above formulae.
We have to use Radians

so convert Latitude, Longitude and Direction to Radians:

```
    oldLatitude = Math.PI * oldLatitude / 180;
    oldLongitude = Math.PI * oldLongitude / 180;
    currentDirection = Math.PI * currentDirection / 180.0;
```

then convert new Longitude and latitude from Radians to Degree again

```
            newLatitude = 180 * newLatitude / Math.PI;
            newLongitude = 180 * newLongitude / Math.PI;
```